# LAN connection loses network access randomly

Tags: windows-7, networking

Windows 7 is a great OS but there are some problems which should be solved from Microsoft as fast as possible. On my Computer the LAN connection randomly loses its connection. I don't know why but I think this problem depends on my network driver which is only available for Windows XP (where it always worked perfectly).

I can not reproduce this issue. Has anybody here had the same problem?

Comment: Hmmm... your NIC driver is only available for Windows XP and you're wondering why it doesn't work 100% on Windows 7? You're also thinking that this is an issue that Microsoft should fix ASAP? Well good luck in your quest.

Comment: s/looses/loses/

Comment: try a static ip address.. it might stop it from happening...

Comment: @retracile: you missed the `g`: `s/looses/loses/g`  :)

Comment: ask for your Ethernet card manufacturer, not for Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have **VirtualCloneDrive** installed by any chance? I had a similar issue with my network connection. After lots of debugging I finally discovered that the device driver of VirtualCloneDrive was causing deadlocks in the kernel. Uninstalling the driver and application completely solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling IPv6 in adapter settings.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you use a driver that is not specifically made for an Operating System (you are running Windows 7, still, the driver is for Windows XP) hardware problems or performance issues are to be expected.

My advice and probably the best you will get is to get a more updated driver that is made for windows 7 or update your ethernet hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a faulty cable. If your driver worked fine under XP, there's no reason why it shouldn't work fine under 7. As Vannus said, disabling IPv6 is worth a try.

What exactly is the mode of failure, are you unable to access or ping websites? Can you ping your gateway? Or does the entire link drop?