# Network randomly loses connection and reconnects after 2 minutes

Tags: windows-10, networking, lan, network-adapter, wired-networking

I got some networking issues and already tried a lot of stuff. First of all I'll give you some hardware infos and then I'll write a list of stuff I already tried. I really hope you can help me here.

Hardware specs from HWinfo with overview and network cards: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKL5g.jpg

I got a wired network from my PC directly to the Fritz!Box (07.27) with fixed IPv4 (DNS: 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8) and automatic IPv6. I got a DS-Lite-Tunnel connection.

**The issue:**
My network randomly disconnects and reconnects after about 2 minutes (+/- 30 seconds). I am not sure about it, but it seems like the connection is breaking down more often if under load.

**What I already tried:**

- Installing a new network card
- Using a different cable
- Reinstalling all network drivers
- Reset winsock
- Reset dns cache
- Disabled energy management on network cards

(Probably more stuff I already forgot)

The issue still persists. Looking in the eventmanager I just find some logs about disconnecting and shortly after network identification and reconnecting.

I'd really appreciate any hints about what I can still try.

I also checked othere posts here, but that didn't really help ([Post 1](https://superuser.com/questions/80486/lan-connection-loses-network-access-randomly), [Post 2](https://superuser.com/questions/1340470/computer-losing-wired-connection-for-a-couple-seconds-and-reconnects) and [Post 3](https://superuser.com/questions/166122/losing-internet-connection-after-few-minutes-5-10-maybe))

Comment: Why do you assume it's your computer and not the Fritz!Box?

Comment: Realtek make really bad network cards. Was the replacement also a Realtek?  Something to try - statically assign an IP address to the interface - if problem goes away its likely dhcp related.

Comment: @user1292580 How could I test that? All other devices (wired and wireless) connected on the Fritz!Box keep their connection. Therefore I assumed that the problem isn't the Fritz!Box

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like faulty cabling or wiring / sockets. Also, your HwInfo shows you are connecting at 100mbps, but unless you have a very old Fritzbox, your Fritzbox most likely supports Gigabit Ethernet.  Since you are not getting a 1000mbps link that also points toward a possible cable / wiring issue.

Ensure you have a good Cat 6 ethernet cable and plug it directly into a different port on the FritzBox. If you are not directly connecting to the fritzbox and you are using built-in wired sockets you could have a damaged ethernet jack and this will also cause random drops.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The 100mbit is the on onboard. NIC, however I've already installed a new one (screenshot 3) with 1000mbit. 

I've already tried it with a different cable and tried all 4 ports of the fritz!box.